# The type or namespace name 'AppUser' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, namespaces

.Net 5.0.1 has been installed. Prompts "ctrl + ." aren't providing the "usual" fixes. I have run into a complete wall. What am I missing? This error is thrown when I run
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -o Data/Migrations

[image: API.csproj]

Comment: Do you have two classes with the same name (AppUser) in your solution?

Comment: @UsemeAlehosaini No, I don't. The only other place I have <AppUser> is in the AppUser.cs file

Comment: How many projects in your solution?

Comment: @UsemeAlehosaini only 1 for now.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the project's properties (Specially Framework target) or the xml version of the project file

Comment: @UsemeAlehosaini absolutely

Comment: Not this what I seek, I need the project XML file or properties, you can get it by `right-click` on `project file` and then `Edit Project File`, you will see something like this `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
    <UserSecretsId>d6ae3b82-1375-4788-b13c-76d7a9046a7e</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>`

Comment: @UsemeAlehosaini When I right-click project file is not an option. I saw a different solution that suggested taking that same path. I'd rather TeamViewer with you. I'm "..." this close to putting this off to the side for another week and coming back to it.

Comment: I afraid this is not something allowed here.

Comment: So please try to right-click and scroll until Properties and take a screenshot for the page of Project Properties

Comment: I am sorry but I prefer supporting you here. How to find project properties ? simply the steps in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-project-and-solution-properties?view=vs-2019

Comment: The first tab (Application) is needed

Comment: @UsemeAlehosaini project files and folders

Comment: in your screenshot you just added, there is a file called `API.csproj` ,  please double-click on it and include the xml content of the file in your post

Comment: @UsemeAlehosaini loaded

Comment: Well, I have checked your `API.csproj` file contents and did not find something wrong (according to my knowledge). this problem generally happens when you have multiple projects and there is `conflict in Framework versions among projects`, but this is `not applicable in your case` as you have only `one project`. Hope somebody else has an answer to your question. Please try to reorganize your question by providing a clear description of the problem and when you mention a code paste it as text not as a screenshot to make it easier for others. Good luck.

Comment: @UsemeAlehosaini thank you for the informative feedback. It's been one week. I have another project to work on. I'll cycle back to this one. Happy Holidays.